# How can I dynamically import a DLL into my program? (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, dll

Is there a way I can import a DLL at runtime? For example, like this:

```
Dim lib = ImportDLL("library.dll")
Dim result = lib.someNamespace.someClass.someFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: I would suggest you have a common interface, that way it will be a lot easier to call functions.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably referring to [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). There are a bunch of articles in the net like the one from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163750.aspx). This [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206412/Reflection-101-An-Introduction-to-Reflection-in-NE) is also a good walkthrough.